# Rstudio auto highlight

Tags: r, rstudio

Rstudio automatically highlights all variables of a given script when one selects one of them. However, this does not work when the variable name embeds a `.`. Is there a way to change that ?

See example below:

[image: auto highlight similar entries]

[image: does not work with dots]

Comment: Looks like a bug. Report it to the developers. However, you shouldn’t be using dots in variable names anyway, they introduce ambiguity in connection with S3 method lookup. It’s unfortunate that some base R names also do it wrong.

Comment: ok thanks for the advice. I lets a post on support.rstudio.com

Comment: It could be that RStudio is telling us indirectly not to use dots in variable names.

Comment: The [Google R Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml)  recommends using '.'s in variable names. I'm not sure what is the preferred method. I typically haven't used '.'s in variable names specifically because Rstudio doesn't highlight them.

Answer (score 0):

RStudio internally uses [Ace](https://ace.c9.io/) which does not consider the `.` as part of a word.

This bug has been filed both on [RStudio bug tracker](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200634308/comments/201270893) and on [Ace bug tracker](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/1695) in 2013 and is not solved yet.